# How can this conditional be shortened?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```
if (!this.initialized || (typeof this.activeId !== 'undefined' && options.qualification_id !== this.activeId)) {
    //Stuff
}
```

I want to execute code if the `this.initialized` flag is false or `this.activeId` value isn't the same as `options.qualification_id`. I have to check if `this.activeId` is defined or not because Javascript will return true in the case of `undefined` !== `this.activeId`. The above is the conditional I've come up with, but I hate how long it is. What would be the shortest way to write it?

Comment: If `this.activeId` is defined, are any of the falsey values possible values for it? I.e. can the Id be 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the valid values for `this.activeId` when it's defined are all truthy (e.g. it can't be `0`, `false`, or `null`), you can use:

```
if (!this.initialized || this.activeId && options.qualification_id != this.activeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what you can do to shorten this

```
(!this.initialized || (typeof this.activeId !== 'undefined' && options.qualification_id !== this.activeId))
```

Well first, you can remove the inner parenthesis. According to the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) table, logical AND has a "higher precedence" than logial OR. In other words the parenthesis will be added for you by the interpreter. So, your condition becomes:

```
(!this.initialized || typeof this.activeId !== 'undefined' && options.qualification_id !== this.activeId)
```

Not much better. Another thing you can do is take advantage of JS type conversion. `undefined` values are falsey (are evaluated to `false`), your condition can become:

```
(!this.initialized || this.activeId && options.qualification_id !== this.activeId)
```

However, this may insert a silent bug since an `activeId` of `0` will also be evaluated to `false`. You can solves this using the `in` operator which checks to see if the property exists on the object or on one of its prototypes (To make sure the property doesn't come from one of its prototypes you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method instead).

```
(!this.initialized || 'activeId' in this && options.qualification_id !== this.activeId).
```

Now to be honest, this doesn't look so much better to me. As a rule, whenever the line becomes too long, just split it in multiple lines to increase readability.

```
var qualificationIsDifferent = options.qualification_id !== this.activeId;
var isNotActive = this.hasOwnProperty('activeId') && qualificationIsDifferent;
var shouldDoStuff = !this.initialized || isNotActive;

if ( shouldDoStuff ) { ... }
```

Note that by using the above approach you lose some of the benefits of the [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).
It really depends on your goal, sometimes more verbose means more readable.